# Laravel - show only .. amount of tablerows and then make a new subpage for it

Tags: html, css, database, laravel

I would like to only show 10 users per page, and have paginate numbers so we can see users per 10. Anyone a idea how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please post what you tried so far

Comment: Nothing yet since i have no idea how to do it, thats why i asked

Comment: Well you could start with cutting this task in to smaller pieces. Start for example with just showing the users on your page without pagination. When you have that going you can start to add pagination to it. We are not here to provide code for you.

Comment: I already got everything set but the pagination

Comment: Then show some code.

Comment: Got it set with laravel pagination with the other anwser, thanks tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination), you can use Laravel's pagination on any collection.

Just return a paginator of your users:

```
User::all()->paginate(10);
```

And in your view:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
     //Display datas
@endforeach

{{ $users->links() }}
```

> The above code is just an exemple.

Comment: $users = DB::table('users')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15)->get();
       return view('profile/members', ['users' => $users]);

Thats what i got till now, but it gives a error

Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator.php on line 566 and defined

Comment: Just remove `->get()`

Comment: Works so easy, thanks mate, you maybe got a idea if laravel also has a search button? or something to order the table on for example a number?

Comment: Checkout - DataTables Table plug-in for jQuery. Probally all you need!